# How to "project out" some dimensions of an n-d array?

Tags: matlab

Suppose that *M* is an *n*-dimensional array (of numbers).  one can also think of *M* as an (*n* - *k*)-dimensional array of *k-dimensional arrays*.  I want to generate the array corresponding to applying some function *f* to each one of those *k*-dimensional arrays.

More precisely, I want to generate a new (*n* - *k*)-dimensional array *N* where the value for each cell *N*(*i*<sub>1</sub>, *i*<sub>2</sub>, …, *i*<sub>*n-k*-1</sub>, *i*<sub>*n-k*</sub>) is obtained by applying a (scalar-valued) function *f* to the *k*-dimensional array at *M*(*i*<sub>1</sub>, *i*<sub>2</sub>, …, *i*<sub>*n-k*-1</sub>, *i*<sub>*n-k*</sub>).

(The function *f* is typically some "summarizing function", like the mean, the median, the max, or the min.)

I imagine that the way to do this would involve `arrayfun` in some way, but I have not been able to figure out how to get `arrayfun` to iterate only over the first (*n* - *k*) dimensions of *M*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are only interested in applying simple functions like mean / median / max / min to the *k*-vectors, i.e. functions for which the *k*-dimensional structure of these vectors is irrelevant, then this is the way to go:

```
s = size(M);
N = reshape(fun(reshape(M, prod(s(1 : end - k)), []).'), s(1 : end - k));
```

This code assumes that `fun` operates on the first dimension of its argument, as is the case for `mean`, `median`, `min`, and `max` and many other Matlab standard functions.

It first reshapes *M* into a two-dimensional array, where the first dimension corresponds to the first *n – k* dimensions of *M*, and the second dimension corresponds to the last *k* dimensions of *M*. Through the transpose `fun` operates across the second set of dimensions. It returns a scalar for each column, such that the result can be reshaped back into an (*n – k*)-dimensional array *N* of a form corresponding to the first *n – k* dimensions of *M*.